# What causes my computer fan to stop briefly before resuming spinning?

Tags: dc-motor, fan

I'm building a small fume extractor for soldering.

I have a leftover desktop fan I'll use. I was unsure about the voltage needed, so I hooked it up to my power supply and stepped up the voltage until it started spinning (around 6V but I think most of these fans are 9-12V nominal if I recall). It's drawing 30mA at 9V right now.

If I place my finger on it to arrest the movement the current draw drops to 0. When I release it the fan rotates quickly to some location which I assume is the armature aligning with the magnet. Now, though, it sits stationary for about 2 seconds before resuming spinning.

What's happening in those 2 seconds before it resumes spinning?

Comment: is the label on the fan missing?

Comment: Yes, it's old and has been in my spare parts bin for ages. No idea where it originally came from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare a [typical](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1905201803_Anpec-Elec-APX284EI-PBG_C393729.pdf) BLDC fan controller IC.

[image]

The delay before a restart attempt after 'mechanical lock' is detected and coil current is shut off (Toff) is nominally 2.8 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The fan is protecting itself when you stall it. After you bump into someone while walking, do you immediately take a step forward? Or do you wait a bit and hope they get out of the way?

Comment: I hadn't considered there might be a controller in there, I assumed it'd just be a DC motor.

Comment: It is not. It is a brushless DC motor which means controller mandatory.

Comment: @DKNguyen I think you need to emphasize "motor controller" here, because OP seems to be interpreting it as "microcontroller"

Comment: @Maple Perhaps. It is not a microcontroller on there but a specialist motor driver IC that is capable of some of its own smarts as well as power drive.

Answer (score 0):

> What's happening in those 2 seconds before it resumes spinning?

quite likely the firmware of the motor controller integrated into what is called "Brushless DC motor" detects the fault state and stops for 2 s for the fault to be removed.

Comment: That makes sense, I hadn't considered there might be an MCU in there.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no MCU in there, but rather specialized chip like [TC642](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21756C.pdf), for example. The behavior of "Fan Auto-Restart" function described in datasheet resembles the effect described. Other fan controllers most likely have similar functions.

Comment: I agree, @Maple! (although, it's worth noting that the only difference between that TC642 and a microcontroller probably is the lack of possibility of the user to program it themselves.)

Comment: I don't claim to know what's inside those chips, but it is definitely not something that can be programmed by anyone, it is just cost-prohibiting step for so cheap products. Most likely it is pure hardware solution, and quite simple at that. See block diagram in the datasheet from @Spehro Pefhany's answer.

Comment: @Maple quite literally look at the flow chart (it says "algorithm") on page 16 of the datasheet you've linked to - that's a set of relatively complex state machines. Sounds like something I'd actually implement in software for a relatively rudimentary CPU, even if that software just ends up being mask ROM.

Comment: I referred to [this chip](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1905201803_Anpec-Elec-APX284EI-PBG_C393729.pdf) from different answer. Nevertheless, the "algorithm" described in this datasheet is nowhere even close to say, I2C state machines in countless chips. And yet only few of them have actual software. The BLDC control (in the case of PC fan) is _very_ primitive task, pretty much just a switch controlled by properly positioned sensors and a simple _analog_ logic with maybe a few digital gates

Comment: @Maple looking at it that way, true.

Comment: @Maple looked up die shots of BLDC/fan controller silicon. So far, found [this](https://zeptobars.com/en/read/Diodes-AH284-brushless-fan-hall-effect-sensor-ThermalRight-X-silent-120). Have to agree, doesn't look like any mask ROM or centralized SRAM anywhere – so not a processor, most likely, but my silicon understanding is weak.

Comment: (credit for the die shot goes to @BarsMonster ([user profile](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/2062/barsmonster)), by the way.)

Comment: Can't say I was surprised. All you need is convert control and hall pulses into voltages (basically two caps), feed those into opamp to get speed signal, use it to adjust frequency of local timer/oscillator for motor PWM, send this to coils via hall-controlled commutator. Under a hundred transistors altogether. Even primitive MCU needs couple thousands of transistors just to get running (higher die density = expensive) and then you still need most of the components above plus software. As I said, it is just cost prohibitive even with economy of scale

Comment: hm, the advantage of having the control in software is the reusability of masks, you only need to change one or two metallization layers to change the ROM to have a different control algorithm, but can still use the same semiconductor layers, no?